# How to make step failed on pylint failure (in Docker Container) on Jenkins

Tags: bash, docker, jenkins

I call pylint in Container in Jenkins step

```
stage('Linting') {
        sh "docker run -v $WORKSPACE:/workspace ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/${DOCKER_TAG}:latest /workspace/lint.sh"
}
```

The problem is it only prints the result but never fails on Jenkins.

Here is bash file, 'lint.sh', to call pylint within the container:

```
#!/bin/bash

awd=$(pwd)
for file in $(find . -name '*.py'); do
        filename=$(basename $file)
        if [[ ${file:(-3)} == ".py" ]] && [[ $filename = *"test"* ]] ; then
                echo "perform PEP8 lint (python pylint blah) for $filename"
                cd $awd && cd $(dirname "${file}") && pylint "${filename}" 
        fi
done
```

Constraint: I must call docker and run the test because I'm using external Jenkins (Cloudbees) to get pip libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is still exiting with exit code 0 as written. If you want to quit immediately after a failed PyLint check, you can add an exit at the end of the check:

```
cd $awd && cd $(dirname "${file}") && pylint "${filename}" || exit 1
```

If you want to check all of the files, and track how many failed PyLint, you can do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

failed=0       # NEW

awd=$(pwd)
for file in $(find . -name '*.py'); do
        filename=$(basename $file)
        if [[ ${file:(-3)} == ".py" ]] && [[ $filename = *"test"* ]] ; then
                echo "perform PEP8 lint (python pylint blah) for $filename"
                cd $awd && cd $(dirname "${file}") && pylint "${filename}"
                if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then      # NEW
                    failed=$(($failed + 1)) # NEW
                fi                          # NEW
        fi
done

exit $failed   # NEW
```

Comment: PERFECT. Thanks!